# If statement to check if post has image

Tags: posts, images

I have the following code. When There is only one image in the backend, the second image shows up with a little question mark instead of nothing. I am looking for a way to check if the image exists first and if so run the code and if not don't.

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('post_image1'), 'thumbnail'); ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php get_the_title(get_field('post_image1')) ?>" />
        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('post_image2'), 'thumbnail'); ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php get_the_title(get_field('post_image2')) ?>" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) will return false if there is no image. So before you echo the image add `if ($image !=false)`